# How do you backup/export datasources in Embarcadero Rapid SQL?

Tags: backup, rapidsql

How do you backup/export datasources for rapid SQL? (Could be typed rapidsql)

It is a hassle for every developer to need to setup their own datasources or if you need to move to a different machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open up `regedit` and export the key: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\Registered Datasources`

The settings can then be imported to any computer by simply running the saved .reg file.

Comment: I was also able to use this technique to migrate my bookmarks between two computers.HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\Rapid SQL\8.7.1\Bookmarks

Answer (score 2):

If you're running one of the later versions, select the Datasource menu, then Manage Datasources.  From there, you can select the individual datasource or All datasources and extract them to an XML file, allowing for easy portability.

Use the same option (Datasource > Manage Datasources) for Importing the datasources into the install on the new machine, or to share datasources between other Rapid SQL users.

Comment: This did not work for me. It did not export the folder structure or the datasources defined by the sybase interfaces file.